# Android App not reading Values after 0x7F

Tags: android, ascii, bluetooth-lowenergy, extended-ascii, android-ble

I have app that receives data from a ble device.
first it sends data as `|0/1|date1|month1|hour1|minute1|date2|month2|hour2|minute2|0x8A|`

App reads every values except `0x8A`.

When i referred some sites it seems that android app reads only `standard ASCI`  which is upto `0x7F`. If yes How will i convert the data to `Extended ASCI` ?
My Data is received as a String .

```
 @Override
        public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                         BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) if (BleUuid.READ_TIME
                    .equalsIgnoreCase(characteristic.getUuid().toString())) {
                final String names = characteristic.getStringValue(0);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        char ff;
                        ff = names.charAt(9);
                        if (ff ==0x8a) {
                            line1.setText("Yes");
                        } else {
                            line1.setText("No");
                        }
```

plz Help me to figure this out.

Comment: Provide your code so we can help you

Comment: Added Code to the question.

Comment: just wondering what do you see when you log `((int) ff)`?

Comment: and maybe this works `if (ff == '\u008a') {`

Comment: Yes thanks it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (ff == '\u008a') {
```

It worked for me